# How to write a query for the following scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables.

**Drug_Master**

```
PKDrugId - Int

DrugName - Varchar(25)

DrugType - Varchar(25)
```

**Store_Master**

```
PKStoreId - Int

StoreName - Varchar(25)

StoreLocation - Varchar(25)
```

**Stock_Outward**

```
PKID - Int

FKDrugId - Int

FKStoreId - Int

OutwardQuantity - int
```

I want to display **DrugName** and **StoreName** instead of **FKDrugId** and **FKStoreId** in the Stock_Outward Data. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to join all tables to get `DrugName` and `StoreName`. Like this:

```
SELECT SO.PKID, DM.DrugName, SM.StoreName, SO.OutwardQuantity
FROM Stock_Outward SO 
JOIN Drug_Master DM ON SO.FKDrugId = DM.PKDrugId 
JOIN Store_Master SM ON SO.FKStoreId = SM.PKStoreId
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2735a/1)